# Handling Api errors with wrong querys

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

When I enter the city name correctly everything goes fine but when the user enters the wrong city name it causes this error

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 1006,
  "message": "No matching locations found."}
```

}

How can I handle this error?

Api

```
interface Api{
   @GET("forecast.json")
      suspend fun getCurrentTemp(@Query("key")key : String, @Query("q")q: String, 
             @Query("days")days : Int): Response<Weatherapi>
companion object {
    operator fun invoke(
    ):Api{
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

}

Repository:

```
  abstract class repositoryApi {
      suspend fun <T : Any> CustomResponse(work: () ->Response <T>): T {
        val response: Response<T> = work.invoke()
        if (response.isSuccessful)
            return response.body()!!
        throw Exception(response.message())
}
```

}

handelRequst:

```
 object handelRequst: repositoryApi() {
     suspend fun <T:Any> Requst (response: Response<T>) = CustomResponse { response } }
```

handelCoroutins:

```
object handelCoroutins {
   fun <T:Any> ThreadMain(work:suspend (() -> T) ,callback : ((T) -> Unit),ErrorMessage : 
   ((String) -> Unit))=
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        try{
            val data :T = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async rt@{
                return@rt work()
            }.await()
            callback(data)
        }catch(e : IOException){
            ErrorMessage.invoke("Error C")
        }
    }
```

}

viewModel:

```
class viewModelapi: ViewModel() {
val LivedataErrorhandel = MutableLiveData<String>()
var weather = MutableLiveData<Weatherapi>()
lateinit var job: Job
fun Gethome(key :String , q :String ,days :Int) {
    try {
        job = handelCoroutins.ThreadMain(
            {
                handelRequst.Requst(Api.invoke().getCurrentTemp(key ,q ,days))
            },
            {
                weather.value  = it
            }, {
                LivedataErrorhandel.value = it
            }
        )
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        LivedataErrorhandel.value = "Error C"
    }
}
```

}

main Activity :

```
 viewmodel.weather.observe(requireActivity(), Observer{
```

textViewtemp.text = it.current.temp_c.toString()
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving the full answer I just give you an idea of how you can handle this. Here's some code you might look at carefully I hope you can take this your way.

```
 if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return response.body()!!
        } else {

           //this is a json object that you should return for handle error 
            var error:JSONObject? = null
            try {
             //heres I convert error response to json object
              error = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())

            //you may know how can you get this exception on your api implementation area 
            throw CustomException(error)

                
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                throw Exception("Something is wrong !! ")
            }

      

        }
```

**CustomException class**

```
class CustomException(error:JsonObject):Exception()
```

*heres how you should implement*

```
try {
    job = handelCoroutins.ThreadMain(
        {
            handelRequst.Requst(Api.invoke().getCurrentTemp(key ,q ,days))
        },
        {
            weather.value  = it
        }, {
            LivedataErrorhandel.value = it
        }
    )
} catch (e: IOException) {
    LivedataErrorhandel.value = "Error C"
}catch(error:CustomException){
   //heres you got the json object }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still the same error :(

Comment: what do you really except from the response ??